# How to select all words at a time to apply operations at same time

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Here is my sample data:

```
data=[1,SanjayMehra, HR, P1, Hyderabad(HYD), 01/12/1976, M], 
[2,AnanyaMishra, Admin, P2,Delhi(DEL), 02/05/1968, F], 
[3,RohanDiwan, Account, P3, Mumbai(BOM), 01/01/1980, M], 
[4 ,SoniaKulkarni, HR, P1, Hyderabad(HYD), 02/05/1992, F], 
[5, AnkitKapoor, Admin ,P2, Delhi(DEL), 03/07/1994, M]
```

I am trying to put inverted commas over every words here:
The expected output is

```
data=["1", "SanjayMehra", "HR", "P1", "Hyderabad(HYD)", "01/12/1976", "M"], 
["2","AnanyaMishra", "Admin", "P2", "Delhi(DEL)", "02/05/1968", "F"], 
["3","RohanDiwan", "Account", "P3", "Mumbai(BOM)", "01/01/1980", "M"], 
["4" ,"SoniaKulkarni", "HR", "P1", "Hyderabad(HYD)", "02/05/1992", "F"], 
["5", "AnkitKapoor", "Admin" ,"P2", "Delhi(DEL)", "03/07/1994", "M"]
```

Right now I am putting multiple cursors using Alt+click before start and after end of each word and then pressing inverted commas in Visual studio code.
With this approach I have to place it more no of times when word count increases.
I am trying to find any more smarter and efficient way of achieving this through Visual studio code or programming language like Python

Comment: Find and replace commas with commas and quotes?

Comment: Is `3 RohanDiwan` correct?  With no comma between them?

Comment: And some spaces after a comma sometimes but not always?  And is `4 ,SoniaKulkarni` correct - with a space before the comma?  Your data seems a little unstructured.

Comment: And no comma between `P2 Delhi(DEL)`?

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/Z3ylUU/1 and find: `(?<=\[|, |,)([^ ,\n\]]+)(?!\n)` - it does assume you have commas between the fields despite your not having them.

Comment: Hey @Mark, thanks I have updated the data. I need to take a look at regex

Comment: I have seen the link @Mark.,It looks nice and good way to me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DsSxGw/1).

Using this Find: `(?<=\[|, |,)([^ ,\n\]]+)(?!\n)`

and Replace: `"$1"`

It does assume that you do have commas between all the fields although your initial data was missing a couple of them.

Positive Lookbehind `(?<=\[|, |,)` with alternatives - where to start the matches, following a `[` or `,`  or `,`

1st Capturing Group `([^ ,\n\]]+)` stop at those characters: space, newline or `]`

Negative Lookahead `(?!\n)` not followed by a newline - you might not need this if your data is simply one long input, without newlines.